# Checking localstorage in Liquid

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to make a collection page password protected in Shopify (liquid).

I'm trying to check if localstorage item "Password" is set with the right value.
If that's the case include 'snippet'.

Whats the best approach to do something like this?

This will break the js earlier cuz of the %}:

```js
if (!localStorage.getItem("password")) {
  {% include 'protected-collection-form' %}
} else {
  {% include 'protected-collection' %}
}
```

Comment: You are mixing server side and client side code. You want AJAX

Comment: https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/customize-shopify-password-pages-with-the-password-liquid-template

Comment: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/online-store/themes/password-page

Comment: And how would i use AJAX in this scenario? I cannot make a call to specific snippet. Because its not a page.

Comment: Look at the links I sent you. They tell you how to use passwords. What you want is likely not useful compared to using the password correctly

Comment: you can check `password` variable. If it is empty, meaning there is no localstorage item set for the current collection page

Comment: @AfzalK. they are trying to read the localStorage var on the server instead of looking at the the server session which should show the user is logged in or not

Comment: Im trying to secure a page with a global password (not customer connected). So whenever someone goes to shoplink.com/collection/thecollection, it comes up with a password input field. Only people with the password (special customers) can enter. @AfzalK.

Comment: you can try the app like Locksmith

Comment: @DylanDoldersum .. this is a good question!

Answer (score 0):

You can't access frontend JS in server-side liquid. Do this instead.

On the password submission store the password in cart's attribute using a fetch.

```
await fetch('/cart/update.js',{
    method:'post',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body:JSON.stringify({'attributes':{'password':"some password"}})
}).then(d => location.reload());
```

and now you can use liquid like this:

```
{% if cart.attributes.password == "some password" %}
  {% include 'protected-collection-form' %}
{% else %}
  {% include 'protected-collection' %}
{% endif %}
```